# How to abandon changes in VSS for absent/gone user?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to clean up a project in VSS2005 so it can Built one last time for a maintenance release before moving into TFS.  However, I have one file that is currently checked out to a user who no longer exists, not even in the VSS database.  We don't know what changes the user made to the file, but we don't care.  We just want the checkout removed.

How is this to be done?  There doesn't seem to be any options for this.

Or are we just screwed with no path out of the hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log in SourceSafe Admin as admin and undo checkouts of the gone user from there.

Here you can learn more details:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150648

Comment: Excellent!  Never occurred to me to log into VSS as Admin.  I've logged into the VSS admin tool as Admin of course. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

As sometimes happens, after posting the question an idea occurred to me.  I have noticed in times past that when creating a new user for VSS, the administrator can either give the user the same username as he or she logs in to his or her PC as, and not specify a password for VSS, thus letting the user's security context govern, or the administrator can specify a VSS password for the user.

Here is what I did:

1. Recreated the user in VSS Admin, as the Administrator
2. Gave the user a specific password
3. Started VSS, and selected File --> Open Source Safe Database
4. Selected the VSS database, filled in the Username with the new user's username (logging in as a different user)
5. When challenged for password, entered the password I assigned to the user
6. At this point I was then able to Undo the Checkout

Whew!